# How to split dataframe in R to conduct statistical tests?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, correlation

I have 3 variables, `A1`, `A2` and `A3`

- `A1` is temperature
- `A2` is month
- `A3` is location

`A2` has 2 months - March and May.`A3` has 2 cities - Chennai and Dubai.

but when I do a correlation between `A1` and `A3`:

`cor(A1,A3, method = "pearson") 
  'y' must be numeric`

How can I fix this, please?

Many Thanks,
Ishack

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: You cannot correlate nominal/ dichotomous data with continuous. You could do a `?t.test` or `?wilcox.test` for `A1 vs A2` and `A1 vs A3`. Please read and watch youtube videos on "correlation" and the two tests I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer to [Correlations with unordered categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-unordered-categorical-variables#112674) will help.

Comment: Can I use t.test instead of the correlation?

Comment: A t-test would test the null hypothesis that the average temperatures between the two cities are equal. A paired t-test would test the null hypothesis that pairs of temperature readings taken at the same time are equal. A correlation would explain the degree to which increases in temperature in Chennai are associated with increases in temperature in Dubai. Which hypothesis do you wish to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to split the data, but the first question to answer is "what hypothesis do I wish to test?"

Here is example code using average daily high temperatures in Chennai and Dubai from timeanddate.com

```
# data collected from average high temperatures collected from 2005 - 2015
# https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/india/chennai/climate
# https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/united-arab-emirates/dubai/climate
rawData <- "
temperature,month,city
75,Jan,Dubai
78,Feb,Dubai
83,Mar,Dubai
92,Apr,Dubai
100,May,Dubai
103,Jun,Dubai
106,Jul,Dubai
107,Aug,Dubai
102,Sep,Dubai
96,Oct,Dubai
87,Nov,Dubai
79,Dec,Dubai
86,Jan,Chennai
89,Feb,Chennai
93,Mar,Chennai
97,Apr,Chennai
102,May,Chennai
100,Jun,Chennai
97,Jul,Chennai
95,Aug,Chennai
95,Sep,Chennai
92,Oct,Chennai
87,Nov,Chennai
86,Dec,Chennai"

tempData <- read.csv(text=rawData)

# t-test for average temperatures
t.test(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
       tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai","temperature"],
       paired=FALSE)

# paired t-test
t.test(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
       tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai","temperature"],
       paired=TRUE)
# correlation
cor(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
    tempData[tempData$city =="Chennai","temperature"])
```

### Two Sample t-test

The two sample t-test tests the null hypothesis that the two means are equal, irrespective of the association between data collected between the two groups in the test. Sometimes the association between two groups may be based on time (as in the case of the temperature data), but the pairing may be based on other characteristics (e.g. twins in a study that has test and control groups where each pair of twins is randomly assigned to test and control groups).

```
> t.test(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
+        tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai","temperature"],
+        paired=FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tempData[tempData$city == "Dubai", "temperature"] and tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai", "temperature"]
t = -0.24817, df = 15.546, p-value = 0.8073
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.765568  6.932235
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 92.33333  93.25000
```

Since 0 is within the 95% confidence interval, we accept the null hypothesis that there is no difference in the monthly average high temperatures between Chennai and Dubai.

### Paired t-test

The paired t-test calculates the difference between the pairs of observations and tests the null hypothesis that the average difference is 0.

```
> # paired t-test
> t.test(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
+        tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai","temperature"],
+        paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  tempData[tempData$city == "Dubai", "temperature"] and tempData[tempData$city == "Chennai", "temperature"]
t = -0.39555, df = 11, p-value = 0.7
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.017343  4.184009
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
             -0.9166667
```

Since 0 is within the 95% confidence interval, we accept the null hypothesis that there is no difference in the monthly average high temperatures between Chennai and Dubai, when the test is conducted on the differences in pairs of monthly average high temperature values.

### Correlation

The Pearson correlation measures the strength of the linear relationship between two variables, -1.0 = perfect negative correlation, 0 = no linear correlation, and 1 = perfect positive correlation.

```
> cor(tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"],
+     tempData[tempData$city =="Chennai","temperature"])
[1] 0.7929018
>
```

A correlation of 0.79 indicates a strong positive linear relationship between monthly average high temperatures in Dubai and Chennai.

### Technique used to split the data

Since I created a raw data file and loaded it into R with `read.csv()`, I used the `[` form of the extract operator to extract rows based on the value of the `city` column. I also created the raw data file in monthly order for each city, so the order of values in each subset matches by month, enabling a straightforward use of the pairwise t-test.

```
# extract temperature values for Dubai
tempData[tempData$city =="Dubai","temperature"]
```

A wide variety of techniques can be used to subset data from an R data frame, such as the `which()` function and the `sqldf()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Len.

Comment: @IshackMarshook please accept the answer if you found it to be helpful.

Comment: done, Len. Can i ask a few more questions please?

Comment: @IshackMarshook - if your followup questions are directly related to this one, yes. Otherwise, please post a new question and the SO community will answer it. Part of SO etiquette is that a post focuses on a single question.